# Jquery Center image in a slider div

Tags: jquery

I want to center the image in a `div`. My code is,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper { 
            background:#EFEFEF; 
            margin: auto; 
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 20px !important;
            width: 800px;
            padding-top: 5px;
        }
        .scrolls { 
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            height: 400px;
        } 
        .imageDiv { 
            margin: 0;
            height: 400px;
        } 
        .imageDiv img { 
            max-height: 400px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-left:20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var wh=$(window).height()/4;
            $('.wrapper').css('margin-top',wh);
        });
        $(window).load(function(){
            var tw = 0;
            $.each($('.imageDiv img'), function() {
                tw += $(this).width();
            });
            $('.imageDiv').width(tw);
            $('.imageDiv img').click(function(){
                var imgid=$(this).attr('id');
                var width = $(imgid).width();
                var margin = width/2;
                $(imgid).css("margin-left","-"+margin);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="scrolls">
            <div class="imageDiv">
                    <img src="001_19_3.jpg" id="img1"/>
                    <img src="002_21_3.jpg" id="img2"/>
                <img src="003_19_3.jpg" id="img3"/>
                <img src="004_19_3.jpg" id="img4"/>
                <img src="005_15_3.jpg" id="img5"/>
                <img src="NB_1a_3.jpg"  id="img6"/>
                <img src="NB_2_3.jpg"   id="img7"/>
                <img src="NB_3_3.jpg"   id="img8"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If i click an image in the slider, that image should go to the center of the div. And also the scroller want to move according to the position of the image. Any one can help? please!

Comment: To center an element you'll have to use CSS. jQuery is just the tool to set those values. So this is in fact a CS question, not a JS question…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.imageDiv img').click(function() {
    var imgid = $(this).attr('id');
    var width = $(imgid).width();
    var margin = width / 2;

    var cssObj = {
        'margin-left': '-' + margin,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': '50%'
    }

    $(imgid).css(cssObj);
});
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply, I tried this, but not working for me. Images are not moving to the center.

Comment: Ok, try modifying the `.wrapper` css like `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;`